# How to Update Text of TextBlock in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Whenever I am Trying to update my Text to TextBlock. It is throwing the following exception: "Object reference set to null".

My Code:

```
<UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" >
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="TbcontentName" FontWeight="SemiBold"  />
    </Border>
</UniformGrid>
```

i am using this TextBlock In another Window

```
if((setMainWindowCall.Try("TbcontentName") as TextBox).Text != null)
    (setMainWindowCall.FindName("TbcontentName") as TextBox).Text = _nameOfUc;
```

Comment: Please ignore or remove comma..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `... as TextBox` where you define `TbcontentName` to be a `TextBlock` in your XAML, so the dynamic cast returns `null` and a NullPointerException is thrown when you try to access the `.Text`-Property. Either change `as TextBox` to `as TextBlock` in your code or change

```
<TextBlock ... x:Name="TbcontentName" ... />
```

to

```
<TextBox ... x:Name="TbcontentName" ... />
```

Comment: I can not use TextBox because its a Label